# .NET library for kerberos authentication at PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, postgresql, mono, kerberos

I'm looking for .Net library to deal with PostgreSQL server that uses kerberos authentication. The environment is Debian linux, PostgreSQL 8.4 and mono 2.6.7.

I was trying to do that with Npgsql, but it supports two types of authentication only: passwords-based and "integrated security". As i know, integrated security is windows-specific mechanism and has nothing common with kerberos.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The Integrated Security is Windows SSPI, which can either be Kerberos or NTLM depending on how your machine is configured.

Comment: Nope. I've explored Npgsql source code and sure that SSPI is not Kerberos (or Npgsql developers don't know that :) ). I've developed Kerberos authentication in Npgsql myself.

Comment: The nice thing about SSPI is that you as an application developer don't have to care about the underlying authentication method. So Npgsql developers just hand it off to SSPI and trust it to do its job. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSPI . SSPI is Kerberos based assuming you configured the machines correctly.

Comment: @chotchki: That's the point. It's kerberos-based, but it's not kerberos. And SSPI is windows-only. If you look at the tags, you see mono, if you read the question, you see Linux, which is not Windows, and hence only supports kerberos, not the proprietary SSPI extension.